# Installation of Ubuntu on Lenovo B480 Laptop

Tags: lenovo

I have Lenovo B480 Laptop, a year old, having Windows 7 64 bit installed. Now, I want to install ubuntu desktop on it.

So, would like to know whether my laptop hardware is having 100% compatibility with ubuntu or not. My lenovo laptop specification is as given below.

```
Intel Core i5-3210 3rd Gen Processor
4 GB DDR3 RAM (Single Slot)
500 GB Toshiba SATA Hard Drive
Finger Print Reader for authentication
WebCam
Intel 4000 HD Graphics Card
Intel WiFi NIC
Realtek Ethernet Gbps NIC
```

Also, would like to know which ubuntu version is compatible with my laptop. Hope, it should be 11.10 & later.

Which application will be used to detect & make "Finger Print Device" fully Functional?

Comment: Make sure to download the latest 14.04.1 iso, do NOT use any thing below that (other than 12.04 but I still reccomend using 14.04) The best way to test hardware is to boot a live CD and play around in the Live Environment before installing.

Answer (score 0):

Its compatible 100% !
No problems at all !

But it would be good to download the intel graphics download utility from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads
Then you have to add the gpg key do an upgrade.
And maybe you should check for any proprietary drivers that you may need on software sources , additional drivers.

Your laptop has an i5 so you could install the 64bit version.

Now about the Fingerprint scanner check this guide: http://tryitnw.blogspot.gr/2013/02/easy-steps-to-enable-finger-print.html

Comment: Ubuntu Linux currently only support PRC... What does it mean? I have found these words on this URL: "http://www.thinkpro.sk/images/products-files/Lenovo_B580_B480.pdf"